# How do I pass parameters to Azure DSC extension while using Azure Automation?

Tags: azure-resource-manager, dsc

As per (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-dsc-template#default-configuration-script) you can not pass arguments if default configuration script is used. So how can I use both Azure Automation onboarding and pass argument to DSC script at the same time? It seems to be impossible to do both.

```
  "resources": [
    {
      "name": "Microsoft.Powershell.DSC",
      "type": "extensions",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines', parameters('swarmmanager1Name'))]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "DSC"
      },
      "properties": {
        "publisher": "Microsoft.Powershell",
        "typeHandlerVersion": "2.26",
        "type":  "DSC",
        "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
        //"forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('DSCExtensionManagerTagVersion')]",
        "settings": {
          "wmfVersion": "latest",
          "configurationArguments": {
            "RegistrationKey": {
              "UserName": "PLACEHOLDER_DONOTUSE",
              "Password": "[parameters('RegistrationKey')]"
            },
            "CustomData" :  "hello from ARM",
            "RegistrationUrl": "[parameters('registrationUrl')]",
            "NodeConfigurationName": "SwarmManager.localhost",
            "RebootNodeIfNeeded": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
      ]
    },
```

DSC configuration

```
Configuration SwarmManager
{
    param
    (
[string] $CustomData
    )

    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PSDesiredStateConfiguration
    Import-DscResource -ModuleName PackageManagement -ModuleVersion "1.1.7.0"

    Node localhost
    {

        PackageManagement xPSDesiredStateConfiguration {
            Ensure = 'present'
            Name   = "xPSDesiredStateConfiguration"
            Source = "PSGallery"

        } 

        File DumpParameters {
            Destinationpath = "c:\out.txt"
            Contents = "Hello $CustomData"
        }
    }
}
```

Error received

`The DSC Extension received an incorrect input: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'CustomData'`

Comment: this looks fine, well apart from you trying to pass too many parameters, not sure why it errors on this one

Comment: This seems to be result of using `default configuration script` instead of custom configuration file. `default configuration script` does not accept any custom parameters at all. I'm not sure how I can use Azure Automation in extension and still pass parameter to script

Comment: wth is default configuration script? you can pass custom parameters to dsc no big deal

Comment: If you register with DSC pull server then you can not pass any arguments other then local LCM settings (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/extensions-dsc-template##Default-Configuration-Script), the only way to pass arguments if you use configuration file